# How to draw a pointing arrow progress using QPainter

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to draw something like this:

[image]

So far what I got:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'm not figuring out how to properly draw the left side of the "middle" widget to fit in the "first" widget, the same applies to the last/middle.

I'm also struggling with properly drawing the ">" shape of the arrow, when I resize the arrows get deformed.

```
class ArrowWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QString text;
    enum Position { FIRST, MIDDLE, LAST };
    Position position;

    ArrowWidget(QWidget* parent, QString text, Position position)
        : QWidget(parent), text(text), position(position) 
    {
    }
    
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        QPainterPath path;

        // Adjust to correctly draw the arrow point.
        int borderRadius = 12; 
        int arrowSize = 12;

        switch (position)
        {
            case FIRST:
            {
                path.moveTo(borderRadius, 0);
                path.lineTo(width() - arrowSize, 0);
                path.lineTo(width(), arrowSize);
                path.lineTo(width(), height() - arrowSize);
                path.lineTo(width() - arrowSize, height());
                path.lineTo(borderRadius, height());
                path.quadTo(0, height(), 0, height() - borderRadius);
                path.lineTo(0, borderRadius);
                path.quadTo(0, 0, borderRadius, 0);
                break;
            }
            case MIDDLE:
            {
                path.moveTo(borderRadius, 0);
                path.lineTo(width() - arrowSize, 0);
                path.lineTo(width(), arrowSize);
                path.lineTo(width(), height() - arrowSize);
                path.lineTo(width() - arrowSize, height());
                path.lineTo(borderRadius, height());
                path.quadTo(0, height(), 0, height() - borderRadius);
                path.lineTo(0, borderRadius);
                path.quadTo(0, 0, borderRadius, 0);
                break;
            }
            case LAST:
            {
                path.moveTo(width(), 0);
                path.lineTo(width() - borderRadius, 0);
                path.quadTo(width(), 0, width(), borderRadius);

                // Bottom right corner
                path.lineTo(width(), height() - borderRadius);
                path.quadTo(width(), height(), width() - borderRadius, height());

                path.lineTo(0, height());
                path.lineTo(0, 0);
                break;
            }
        }

        /*
        path.moveTo(arrowSize, 0);
        path.lineTo(0, arrowSize);
        path.lineTo(0, height() - arrowSize);
        path.lineTo(arrowSize, height());
        path.lineTo(width() - borderRadius, height());
        path.quadTo(width(), height(), width(), height() - borderRadius);
        path.lineTo(width(), borderRadius);
        path.quadTo(width(), 0, width() - borderRadius, 0);
        path.lineTo(arrowSize, 0);
        */
        painter.fillPath(path, QColor("#4699ea"));
        painter.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 255));
        painter.drawText(0, 0, width(), height(), Qt::AlignCenter, text);
        painter.end();
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindowClass())
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        setStyleSheet("#centralWidget { background-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 80); }");

        QWidget* widget = new QWidget(this);
        QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
        layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        layout->setSpacing(0);

        ArrowWidget* arrowWidget = new ArrowWidget(widget, "First", ArrowWidget::FIRST);    
        layout->addWidget(arrowWidget);
        arrowWidget = new ArrowWidget(widget, "Middle", ArrowWidget::MIDDLE);
        layout->addWidget(arrowWidget);
        arrowWidget = new ArrowWidget(widget, "Last", ArrowWidget::LAST);
        layout->addWidget(arrowWidget);

        setContentsMargins(32, 32, 32, 32);
        setCentralWidget(widget);
    }
private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass *ui;
};
```

Comment: If you want your `ArrowWidget` to resize proportionally, then you're likely better off calculating values like `arrowSize` and `borderRadius` as a percentage of the widget's width and height rather than as fixed constants.  (e.g. `const int arrowSize = ((float)width()) * 0.05f;` or similar)

Answer (score 0):

```
class ArrowWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QStringList textList;
    int Position;

    ArrowWidget(QWidget* parent, QStringList list, int pos)
    : QWidget(parent), textList(list), Position(pos) {}

void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    int arrowMidSize = height() / 2;
    double arrowWidth = width() / (textList.size() + 1);

    for (int p = 0; p < textList.size(); p++) {
        QPainterPath path;
        if (p==0) {
            path.moveTo(p*arrowWidth, 0);
        } else {
            path.moveTo(p*arrowWidth - arrowMidSize, 0);
        }
        if (p==textList.size()-1) {
            path.lineTo((p+1)*arrowWidth, 0);
            path.lineTo((p+1)*arrowWidth, height());
        } else {
            path.lineTo((p+1)*arrowWidth - arrowMidSize, 0);
            path.lineTo((p+1)*arrowWidth, arrowMidSize);
            path.lineTo((p+1)*arrowWidth - arrowMidSize, height());
        }
        if (p==0) {
            path.lineTo(p*arrowWidth, height());
            path.lineTo(p*arrowWidth, 0);
        } else {
            path.lineTo(p*arrowWidth - arrowMidSize, height());
            path.lineTo(p*arrowWidth, arrowMidSize);
            path.lineTo(p*arrowWidth - arrowMidSize, 0);
        }
        if (p == Position) {
            painter.fillPath(path, QColor(0,0,255));
        } else {
            painter.fillPath(path, QColor(255,255,255));
        }
        painter.setPen(QColor(100, 100, 100));
        painter.drawPath(path);
        path.clear();
        painter.setPen(QColor(200, 200, 200));
        painter.drawText(p*arrowWidth, 0, arrowWidth - arrowMidSize, height(), Qt::AlignCenter, textList[p]);
    }
    painter.end();
}
};
    
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    resize(400,300);
    setStyleSheet("#centralWidget { background-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 80); 
}");

    QWidget* widget = new QWidget(this);
    widget->resize(300,30);
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout->setSpacing(0);

    ArrowWidget* arrowWidget = new ArrowWidget(widget, {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"}, 1);
    layout->addWidget(arrowWidget);

    setContentsMargins(32, 32, 32, 32);
    //setCentralWidget(widget);
}
};
```